# Why is the "psci-cpuidle" cpuidle driver not used?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, raspberry-pi, arm

On my Raspberry Pi 5, I noticed that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver` contained `none`.
So I got the latest kernel sources from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) and enabled `CONFIG_ARM_PSCI_CPUIDLE` in menuconfig.
Compared to the `bcm2712_defconfig`, these are the only changes:

```
CONFIG_CPU_IDLE_MULTIPLE_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_DT_IDLE_STATES=y
CONFIG_DT_IDLE_GENPD=y
CONFIG_ARM_PSCI_CPUIDLE=y
CONFIG_ARM_PSCI_CPUIDLE_DOMAIN=y
```

I compiled and installed the kernel according to this [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html) (specifically the cross-compiling part). It successfully booted and I verified that I am running the new kernel.

Unfortunately, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver` still contains `none`.
As I am out of ideas right now what could be at fault, I hope anybody here can help!